# 'getter for connectionInfo: WifiInfo!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java (Api 31)

Tags: android, wifimanager, android-12, android-api-31

When I want to get info about current wifi connection via WifiManager.connectionInfo I get
this:

> 'getter for connectionInfo: WifiInfo!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

How can I do it in Android 12? (only want to get rssi)

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#S, WifiInfo retrieval is moved to ConnectivityManager API surface. WifiInfo is attached in NetworkCapabilities#getTransportInfo() which is available via callback in NetworkCallback#onCapabilitiesChanged(Network, NetworkCapabilities) or on-demand from ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(Network).

```
final NetworkRequest request =
       new NetworkRequest.Builder()
       .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
       .build();
  final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
       context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
  final NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback() {
       ...
       @Override
       void onAvailable(Network network) {}
 
       @Override
       void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
           WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo();
       }
       // etc.
  };
  connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback); // For request
  connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback); // For listen
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo()

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Kotlin developers who wants to get current connected WiFi name.

```
/**
 * Access connected wifi name from this var ..because we are using listener .. to set value ..
 * @see setCallBack method ..
 */
var connectedWifiName = ""

/**
 * This method will set the connected wifi name for all phones
 * @see connectedWifiName variable
 * @param mContext is the current fragment context ..
 * must be called when permission is granted ..
 * @see [https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo()]
 */
fun setConnectedWifiName(mContext : Context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .build()
        val connManager =
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        connManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, setCallBack())
    } else {
        setWifiName(mContext)
    }

}

/**
 * This method will only be called for new phones from s/31/And -12 -- Snow Cone
 * required ...  ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions
 * need to pass FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO to NetworkCallback(), otherwise you will get "unknow ssid" only
 * @see [https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo()]
 */
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
private fun setCallBack(): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
    val networkCallback =
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(
            FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO
        ) {
            override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
                network: Network,
                networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
            ) {
                super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
                setUpWifiName(networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo)
            }
        }

    return networkCallback

}

/**
 * This method will only be called --- below s/31/And -12 -- Snow Cone
 * @param mContext is current fragment context
 * ACCESS_WIFI_STATE  is required
 * ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION for some specific version --->= 28/0/Oreo
 * @see [https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/wifi/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-permissions] for reference ..
 */
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun setWifiName(mContext : Context) {
    val wifiManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val wifiInfo =
        wifiManager.connectionInfo

    if (wifiInfo?.supplicantState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
        setUpWifiName(wifiInfo)
    }
}

/**
 * Setting exact wifi name from here ..
 * @param wifiInfo is instance of WifiInfo ..
 */
private fun setUpWifiName(wifiInfo: WifiInfo){
    connectedWifiName = wifiInfo.ssid.replace("\"", "")
}
```